# android - without opening a webview , make sure that , the page is requested

Tags: android

I have created one button in Simple UI for android app using eclipse.
I want that if I click on that button then , the request is sent to the specified page , and I don't want to open that particular page. Just want to make sure that the request is posted on that page....

Can any one tell me hows this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make a simple http request something like that and then you can check the status of the response if you need.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com"));
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){}
```